# Add active class to the router link - LitElement

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I have used **`lit-element-router`** and when i try navigating across everything works fine but I am unable to find a way to highlight the active router link.

```
<app-drawer id="drawer" class="drawer" slot="drawer" swipe-open="[[narrow]]">
   <div class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <app-link href="/">Home</app-link>
      <app-link href="/products">Products</app-link>
   </div>
</app-drawer>
```

**Question:** Can I add some kind of attribute to the **`app-link`** to trigger a css class to it.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Can I suggest you how to use @conectate/ct-router? it is simpler to use and understandable

Comment: @HerberthObregon I have already integrated it. Thanks for this new reference though.